# jquery - scrollable inside accordion inside overlay - scrollable doesn't work!

Tags: jquery, horizontal-accordion

First off... i'm only just coming to jquery, so... if anyone has time to point me in the right direction - brilliant!...however, guidance would need to be targeted at a 7 year old ;)

**THE Q**. how do I reference 'this' when it's inside two other jquery object? As far as I can see this is the problem...maybe.

I've got a scrollable that doesn't work inside an accordion that does work,.. all of which is inside an overlay that also works.

It's online, but quite tricky to find:

Go to http://www.jordansokol.com

at the top right of the homepage there is a hidden link that opens the overlay. From this point on, everything I refer to is inside the overlay...

You'll then see a login page - ignore the input fields and just hit the arrow button.

Next page has the accordion (3 panes) In the first, which has the 'T' symbol at the top, there should be a scrollbar.

You'll see it's not working as the text extends below the bounds of the containing div.

I've used this scrollbar quite a few times and so I know it works in other situations.

Last thing, I've firebug-ed the problem and see that the css 'height' is being set to '0'. This scrollbar has the functionality to appear only if there is sufficient content to need it. Therefore, it could be that jquery plugin "jquery.tinyscrollbar.js" isn't firing, or maybe the css 'height' is erroneously being set from the accordion plugin.

Ok, sorry if that's not so concise - it's my best shot!

Thanks in advance...

Scott

Comment: tinyscrollbar has an error on line 42 when you try to initialize it.  i don't know anything about this plugin, but i'd suggest you start there.

Comment: thanks - did you 'read' that there was an error by looking at the file, or was it an error notification from a browser?  S:)

Comment: @scottieclark, just looked in the firebug console.  i've added my comment as an answer.  if it was helpful to you, feel free to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tinyscrollbar has an error on line 42 when you try to initialize it. i don't know anything about this plugin, but i'd suggest you start there.